# How to implement full text search in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, full-text-search

I would like to implement a search function in a django blogging application. The status quo is that I have a list of strings supplied by the user and the queryset is narrowed down by each string to include only those objects that match the string.

See:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        for string in form.cleaned_data['query'].split():
            posts = posts.filter(
                    Q(title__icontains=string) | 
                    Q(text__icontains=string) |
                    Q(tags__name__exact=string)
                    )
        return archive_index(request, queryset=posts, date_field='date')
```

Now, what if I didn't want do concatenate each word that is searched for by a logical AND but with a logical OR? How would I do that? Is there a way to do that with Django's own Queryset methods or does one have to fall back to raw SQL queries?

In general, is it a proper solution to do full text search like this or would you recommend using a search engine like Solr, Whoosh or Xapian. What are their benefits?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest you to adopt a search engine.

We've used [Haystack search](http://haystacksearch.org/), a modular search application for django supporting many search engines (Solr, Xapian, Whoosh, etc...)

Advantages:

- Faster
- perform search queries even without querying the database.
- Highlight searched terms
- "More like this" functionality
- Spelling suggestions
- Better ranking
- etc...

Disadvantages:

- Search Indexes can grow in size pretty fast
- One of the best search engines (Solr) run as a Java servlet (Xapian does not)

We're pretty happy with this solution and it's pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the query you have posted *does* use OR rather than AND - you're using `\` to separate the `Q` objects. AND would be `&`.

In general, I would highly recommend using a proper search engine. We have had good success with Haystack on top of Solr - Haystack manages all the Solr configuration, and exposes a nice API very similar to Django's own ORM.

Comment: He should be using OR if he wants a full text search. His code is clear, but the description is a bit confusing.

Comment: But the .filter() statements are AND'ed together, aren't they? So, each search argument (word) is searched for in the post's title OR the content OR in the related tags. But to show up as a result, a post needs to have all of the search arguments in its title OR content OR tag. 

That's fine and exactly what I wanted to achieve. I'm just curious on how to implement that a result needs only one of the words to be present in one of their attributes (not all of them).

Answer (score 4):

Answer to your *general* question: Definitely use a proper application for this.

With your query, you **always examine the whole content** of the fields (title, text, tags). You gain no benefit from indexes, etc.

With a proper full text search engine (or whatever you call it), **text (words) is (are) indexed** every time you insert new records. So queries will be a lot faster especially when your database grows.

Answer (score 4):

SOLR is very easy to setup and integrate with Django. Haystack makes it even simpler.

Answer (score 2):

For full text search in Python, look at [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/). It allows for very complex queries. The main problem here is that you must find a way to tell your search engine which pages changed and update the index eventually.

Alternatively, you can use [Google Sitemaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) to tell Google to index your site faster and then embed a custom query field in your site. The advantage here is that you just need to tell Google the changed pages and Google will do all the hard work (indexing, parsing the queries, etc). On top of that, most people are used to use Google to search plus it will keep your site current in the global Google searches, too.

Answer (score 2):

I think full text search on an application level is more a matter of what you have and how you expect it to scale. If you run a small site with low usage I think it might be more affordable to put some time into making an custom full text search rather than installing an application to perform the search for you. And application would create more dependency, maintenance and extra effort when storing data. By making your search yourself and you can build in nice custom features. Like for example, if your text exactly matches one title you can direct the user to that page instead of showing the results. Another would be to allow title: or author: prefixes to keywords.

Here is a method I've used for generating relevant search results from a web query.

```
import shlex

class WeightedGroup:
    def __init__(self):  
        # using a dictionary will make the results not paginate
        # but it will be a lot faster when storing data          
        self.data = {}

    def list(self, max_len=0):
        # returns a sorted list of the items with heaviest weight first
        res = []
        while len(self.data) != 0:
            nominated_weight = 0                      
            for item, weight in self.data.iteritems():
                if weight > nominated_weight:
                    nominated = item
                    nominated_weight = weight
            self.data.pop(nominated)
            res.append(nominated)
            if len(res) == max_len:
                return res
        return res

    def append(self, weight, item):
        if item in self.data:
            self.data[item] += weight
        else:
            self.data[item] = weight


def search(searchtext):
    candidates = WeightedGroup()

    for arg in shlex.split(searchtext): # shlex understand quotes

        # Search TITLE
        # order by date so we get most recent posts
        query = Post.objects.filter_by(title__icontains=arg).order_by('-date')
        arg_hits = query.count() # count is cheap

        if arg_hits > 1000:
            continue # skip keywords which has too many hits

        # Each of these are expensive as it would transfer data
        #  from the db and build a python object, 
        for post in query[:50]: # so we limit it to 50 for example                
            # more hits a keyword has the lesser it's relevant
            candidates.append(100.0 / arg_hits, post.post_id)

        # TODO add searchs for other areas
        # Weight might also be adjusted with number of hits within the text
        #  or perhaps you can find other metrics to value an post higher,
        #  like number of views

    # candidates can contain a lot of stuff now, show most relevant only
    sorted_result = Post.objects.filter_by(post_id__in=candidates.list(20))
```